# How to import/add secured backend .jks file in API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I need to create restful service from the secured SOAP endpoint.
Can someone provide the reference link or explain how to import/add secured backend .jks file in WSO2 API Manager to connect SOAP based endpoint.

WSO2 APIM Version : 2.6.0

wss4j-1.6.2

Also let me know how to send signed message to the back end using WSO2 API Manager.

Comment: why do you want to import a JKS?

Comment: Back end is enabled with security. In order to access back end I need to import/install .jks in wso2-  (SOAP UI also need to add .jks to get the response from service)

Comment: So you mean the backend is MTLS enabled?

Comment: Yes, security is applied on backend side, Using backend .JKS I need to achieve this in WSO2 API Manager

Comment: Use this doc. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Mutual+SSL+between+API+Gateway+and+Backend

Comment: I already tried, I am getting "Message is not  signed" as a fault message - In the question already asked suggestion on how to send signed message to the back end.